# Google street view location limitation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

Is there any chance to limit the area where pegman can be dropped?
As an example:
I want visitors of my site were able to see where my office is on map, and if they want, to use GSV to see how it looks like. So if user drops the pegman to the map, I need they will exactly watch to my office.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom streetView config  .. setting the initiali position (coord, angle and pitch)but you can't block the pan  ..

```
           var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(your_lat,your_lng);


           var  mapStreetView = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("pano"),mapProp);

            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
              document.getElementById('pano'), {
                position:  myCenter,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControl: false,
                addressControl: false,
                fullscreenControl: false,
                linksControl: false,
                enableCloseButton: false,
                scrollwheel: false,
                draggable: false,

                pov: {
                  heading: 320,
                  pitch: 5
                }
              });

            mapStreetView.setStreetView(panorama);
```

Comment: For what i know  ...no.. but instead of a map with pegman i suggest you to show directly the streetView  result

Comment: Sounds good, but how can the user switch between map and street view, other than use pegman?

Comment: You can use a custom button .. in my case i sue two div  one near other. One with map, another with streetView .. as you like .